# How to append correct details based upon category?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

If a user **clicks** on `#challenge_category_goal` then the details `for-goal` appear, if the user clicks on `#challenge_category_habit` then the details `for-habit` appear.

```
    <%= f.radio_button :category, 'goal', class: 'date-format-switcher' %>
    <label for="challenge_category_goal">Goal</label>

    <%= f.radio_button :category, 'habit', class: 'date-format-switcher' %>
    <label for="challenge_category_habit">Habit</label>

    <div id='details'>  
      <div id='for-goal'>
        goal attributes
      </div>
      <div id='for-habit'>
        habit attributes
      </div>
    </div>

<script>
  var removed = $('#for-b').detach();
  $('#challenge_category_goal').click(function() {
    $('#details').append(removed);
    removed = $('#for-goal').detach();
  })

  $('#challenge_category_habit').click(function() {
    $('#details').append(removed);
    removed = $('#for-habit').detach();
  })
</script>
```

When the form first **loads** the appropriate category is chosen (based upon code passed on the backend from the user choosing a featured challenge), but the `details` are not changed based upon page load. They only change based upon `.click`. How can I make javascript show correct `details` based upon page load & `.click`?

Comment: Check this one: `https://jsfiddle.net/j7qg8op1/2/`

Comment: Nope. Thanks for trying again. When a featured challenge passed to habit. The habit category was selected, but it showed the attributes for goal @7urkm3n

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use the `checked` status to determine the `show/hide` status:

```
<script>
function updateInfo(){
    if($('#challenge_category_goal').prop('checked')){
        $('#for-goal').show();
        $('#for-detail').hide();
    }else{
        $('#for-goal').hide();
        $('#for-detail').show();
    }
}

$(function() {
  $('#challenge_category_goal').click(updateInfo);
  $('#challenge_category_habit').click(updateInfo);
  updateInfo();
});
</script>
```

I also suggest you to check whether this pure [CSS](http://joegaudet.com/css/html/2013/07/24/styling-radio-buttons.html) method fits your case.

Comment: Thank you so much! Been at this for days :] This was the final piece to the puzzle.

Comment: FML actually the data attributes, which are hidden are still being passed through. You know how to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

Your javascript should be:

```
<script>
$(function() {
  $('#challenge_category_goal').click(function() {
    $('#for-goal').show();
    $('#for-detail').hide();
  });

  $('#challenge_category_habit').click(function() {
    $('#for-goal').hide();
    $('#for-detail').show();
  });

 // Update: To select challenge_category_goal in default
 $('#challenge_category_goal').click();
});
</script>
```

**Explanation**

1. Your javascript must be wrapped in `$(function() {});`, because the events will be attached after document ready!
2. For show hide, just use jquery `show()`, `hide()` functions, they are more simple than remove/attach like what you did!

**Optional improvement**: Make it generic:

```
<% %w( goal habit ).each do |category_name| %>
  <%= f.radio_button :category, category_name, class: 'date-format-switcher category-radio-btn', 'category-name' => category_name %>
  <label for="challenge_category_<%= category_name %>goal"><%= category_name.titleize %></label>
<% end %>

<div id='details'>
  <div id='for-goal' class='category-detail'>
    goal attributes
  </div>
  <div id='for-habit' class='category-detail'>
    habit attributes
  </div>
</div>

<script>
$(function() {
  $('.category-radio-btn').click(function() {
    $('#details .category-detail').hide();
    $('#for-' + $(this).attr('category-name')).show();
  });

  // Update: To select first radio button in default
  $('.category-radio-btn').first().click();
});
</script>
```

Then we just move the section which renders radio buttons to view helper, it will be beautiful and easy to add/modify later! Btw, in the `details` element, I think you will show more info, I don't know how complex they are, so I couldn't make it generic.

Comment: Just tried it. I couldn't get it to work Hieu. For example, when I load the page now it shows everything in both `for-goal` and `for-habit` instead of just one or the other. If I click on the other category though it shows one or the other correctly.

Comment: I also tried it like this, `$('#challenge_category_goal').click(function() {
    $('#for-goal').show();
    $('#for-habit').hide();
  })

  $('#challenge_category_habit').click(function() {
    $('#for-goal').hide();
    $('#for-habit').show();
  })`

Comment: @AnthonyGalli.com Just a small update, check it out pls :)

Comment: Okay sir just plugged it all in. Upon loading page with the category being `habit` I see that it defaulted to `goal` for some reason and it show both `for-goal` and `for-habit` attributes. And if I try to manually change the category it won't change

Comment: Did you try the `Optional Improvement`? I just updated it, sorry, I was missing a dot in jquery selector, so lame :(

Comment: No problem haha. Not it correctly just shows one or the other `for -`, but it shows `goal` even though the featured challenge that was passed in was a `habit` and if I try to manually click habit it still won't click :/

Answer (score 0):

JSFiddle example: https://jsfiddle.net/j7qg8op1/2/

as @Hieu mention about just use `show` and `hide` methods. I'll add some additional helper.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('#challenge_category_goal').click(function() {
    $('#for-goal').show();
    $('#for-habit').hide();
  })

  $('#challenge_category_habit').click(function() {
    $('#for-goal').hide();
    $('#for-habit').show();
  })

})
</script>
```

Comment: Not using turbolinks. Your code hides both when the page loads. To show one or the other the user then has to manually click on the category even though the category is already selected. Is there an alternative to `.click` because I think that's the culprit.

Comment: @AnthonyGalli.com OMG, then just make it show like this -> `$('#for-goal').show();`, html anyway in default will chosen first radio button. i also attached simple example in jsfiddle.

Comment: It doesn't default. I don't want the user to have to click. It should default automatically to the appropriate category `for-goal` or `for-habit` as soon as page loads. Sometimes the page will load with the category `goal` preselected and sometimes the category loaded will be `habit` it all depends on upon which featured challenge a user had selected.

Comment: @AnthonyGalli.com updated my post, just add `checked: true` for your goal radio button.

Comment: I don't want to check to `true`. That defeats the purpose. Ruby passes in the category so sometimes the `category` will be passed in as `habit` and sometimes `goal`.

Comment: You figure out the helper?